# Should I ask to volunteer, even if I just applied for a job with the same organization

Tags: job-search

I just applied for a position with an organization that I am passionate about. I emailed it to the executive director, as requested in the job description.

However, I am also sincerely interested in volunteering for said organization, even if I don't get the job. Sine the ED replied back thanking me for the resume, I'm curious if I can ask if there are any volunteer opportunities or if I should wait until after the job is filled. I don't want to come across like I'm kissing up.

Comment: What do you mean by "volunteer". I would call that an "unpaid internship". Is that what you mean? If so there is probably an application procedure, and just because it is unpaid doesn't mean they don't have to budget for it.

Comment: It's a non-profit, so they have community volunteers that might help out at events every once in a while. It wouldn't be an internship at all. Nevertheless, after reading Myles response below, I believe I'll just hold off until the position is filled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wait until you get a response regarding the position.  You are risking sending a mixed message if they see your name coming in two different paths.  You are able to do more good for the organization by filling the larger position so don't do anything to jeopardize your chances of making maximum impact.